# How do I configure react-intl to have all dialect locales fall back to their parent language?

Tags: react-intl, formatjs

I've built a site that translates nicely between `en` and `zh` locales, using a select element. Now, I'd like to have my code choose the initial locale based on the value of `navigator.language`. This led to my realization that my locale is `en-US`, not `en`. When I applied that value to the locale property of `<IntlProvider />`, a lot of new errors were thrown.

```
Error: [React Intl Error MISSING_TRANSLATION] Missing message: "details.reference" for locale "en-US", using default message as fallback.
```

The UI still looked fine, since the default messages were in English. And I'm guessing that these errors are silenced in production.

But, the same issue occurs in Chinese. If a user has their OS/browser locale set to `zh-HK`, react-intl displays the default messages (in English) instead of the translations in `zh.json`.

**Is there a clever way to fix this?** I know that I could clip the geography part of a locale off before passing it to `<IntlProvider />`, but that seems hackier than necessary...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to get around the problem for now, but hoping to find a better solution.

```
const [locale, setLocale] = React.useState(getBrowserLocale());

...

<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages[locale]}>
```

```
// @see https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt

function getBrowserLocale() {
  switch (navigator.language) {
    case "zh":
    case "zh-Hant":
    case "zh-Hans":
    case "zh-TW":
    case "zh-HK":
    case "zh-CN":
      return "zh";
    // case "zh-CN":
    //   return "zh-CN";
    default:
      return "en";
  }
}

export default getBrowserLocale;
```

Comment: You could use the following:  `const locale =  navigator.language.slice(0, 2)`
Edit: just saw that you said this was hacky. Yea I agree, it sort of is, but it does provide the exact functionality you're looking for.